# How to download a captcha image without a direct link

Tags: python, web-scraping, captcha

I'm trying to access sci-hub.io from a command line client, not defeat its captcha system. When you POST a doi to its frontpage it returns a pdf url of the form http://moscow.sci-hub.io/abc123blah/foo.pdf. If you then request that link, you randomly either get the pdf or a captcha. 
The captcha page has this source:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Для просмотра статьи разгадайте капчу</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body style = "background:white">
        <div>
            <table style = "width:100%;height:100%"><tr><td style = "vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">
            <h2 style = "color:gray;font-family:sans-serif;padding:18px">для просмотра статьи разгадайте капчу</h2>
            <p></p>
            <form action = "" method = "POST">
                <p><img id="captcha" src="/captcha/securimage_show.php" /></p>
                <input type="text" maxlength="6" name="captcha_code" style = "width:256px;font-size:18px;height:36px;margin-top:18px;text-align:center" autofocus /><br>
                <a style = "color:gray;text-decoration:none" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/captcha/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">[ показать другую картинку ]</a>
                <p style = "margin-top:22px"><input type = "submit" value= "Продолжить"></p>
            </form>
            </td></tr></table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

All I can think to do is, request securimage_show.php, save the image, display it to the user, grab their decoding of it, and then POST the response. An example pdf link is http://moscow.sci-hub.io/291193c259b69cc057d74e3eb4965c4f/ong2014.pdf
Something like:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io

pdf_url = "http://moscow.sci-hub.io/3dcd1bf3b82ea549c0a72e9ab195ab78/walter2015.pdf"

r1 = requests.get(pdf_url)

if r1.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/pdf':
    print("Looks like Sci-hub gave us a captcha")

    image = requests.get("http://moscow.sci-hub.io/captcha/securimage_show.php").content
    img = io.BytesIO(image)
    im = Image.open(img)
    im.show()
    captcha_text = input("Enter captcha text: ")

    r2 = requests.post(pdf_url, data = {'captcha_code': captcha_text})

    if r2.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/pdf':
        print("Looks like Sci-hub gave us another captcha")
    else:
        with open("filename.pdf", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        print("saved!")

else:
    print("Got a PDF")
    with open("filename.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
    print("saved!")
```

What I don't have is a way to get the original captcha image that was generated when I first requested the pdf. When I request another captcha image from securimage_show.php, it generates a new one so the POST response is incorrect. How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should do both actions in a single session? See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew for pointing me in the right direction. I needed to set up a session with requests. I assume this session passed a cookie back and forth so that the server could keep track of which was the latest captcha it had sent me. Just a guess, since this is all still a bit magical to me.

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

pdf_url = "http://moscow.sci-hub.io/3dcd1bf3b82ea549c0a72e9ab195ab78/walter2015.pdf"

s = requests.Session()
r1 = s.get(pdf_url)

if r1.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/pdf':
    print("Looks like Sci-hub gave us a captcha")

    image = s.get("http://moscow.sci-hub.io/captcha/securimage_show.php").content
    img = BytesIO(image)
    im = Image.open(img)
    im.show()
    captcha_text = input("Enter captcha text: ")

    r2 = s.post(pdf_url, data = {'captcha_code': captcha_text})

    if r2.headers['Content-Type'] != 'application/pdf':
        print("Looks like Sci-hub gave us another captcha")
    else:
        with open("filename.pdf", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r2.content)
        print("saved!")

else:
    print("Got a PDF")
    with open("filename.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r1.content)
    print("saved!")
```